# Create ZipFile with Password in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder Structure like this :

```
MainFolder
    |
   project.xml 
   SubFolder 1
      |
      Files
        |  
        wallpaper.png
        imp.docx
        pdf_1.pdf
    SubFolder 2
        |
        CategoryFolder
          |  
          Files
             |
             something.txt
```

So the above is my folder structure. I have to create a zipFile to the "MainFolder" with password and zipFile should contain all the files and folders as i have shown above. I was able to create zipFile without password but the requirement is zipFile with password.
So how can i Achieve this. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open), the python zip library only uses password for extracting zip file (and not for creating them):

> pwd is the password used to decrypt encrypted ZIP files.

There are some other packages that claim to allow that. Here's a piece of code that zips all the files in a folder named 'main':

```
from pathlib import Path
import pyminizip

# replace 'main' is your main folder. 
files = [f for f in Path("main").rglob("*") if f.is_file()]

paths = [str(f.parent) for f in files]
file_names = [str(f) for f in files]

# 123456 is the password. 3 is the compression level. 
pyminizip.compress_multiple(file_names, paths, "my.zip", "123456", 3)
```

The alternative solution would be to call the `zip` utility as a separate process using `system`, or preferably `Popen`.

Comment: I used pyminizip for creating zipfile but it takes only source file ex: .txt but in my case its whole directory. So i got stuck here.

Comment: Thank u for the answer. Actually i used pyminizip package to do zip with password. Created a zipfile using "shutil" then used "pyminizip" for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in some packages as pyzipper. According to documentation, this is

> Modification of Python’s zipfile to read and write AES encrypted zip files.

[Source](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipper/)